# #1054 - Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

В sql не силён, составил запрос:

```
insert into avrorades_centro.prices_box(size) 
select value from avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
where  avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid=avrorades_centro.prices_box.idmodx 
and avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid=3
```

сервер ругается ошибкой:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'avrorades_centro.prices_box.idmodx' in 'where clause'

Я так понимаю что он мне говорит что столбца idmodx в базе не существует, но он есть.

Разъясните из-за чего ещё может появляться данная ошибка, и если запрос составлен некорректно, то подскажите как правильнее.
мне нужно скопировать значения из `avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues(value)` в `avrorades_centro.prices_box(size)`, но только те значения у которых `tmplvarid=3` и у которых совпадают значения в столбцах `contentid=idmodx`

Answer (score 1):

> Я так понимаю что он мне говорит что столбца idmodx в базе не существует, но он есть.

Прежде чем найти поле в таблице, нужно найти саму таблицу. А таблица avrorades_centro.prices_box вообще не указана в секции FROM.

```
insert into avrorades_centro.prices_box(size) 
select value 
from avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues, vrorades_centro.prices_box
where avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid=avrorades_centro.prices_box.idmodx 
and avrorades_centro.modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid=3
```

Comment: Спасибо что ответили.
Но вместо того чтобы добавлять значения в существующие поля существующих строк, запрос создаёт новые поля и добавляет значения туда

Comment: Странно было бы, если бы INSERT вместо создания новых записей начал обновлять существующие... используйте UPDATE либо REPLACE.

Comment: `UPDATE `prices_box` SET `size` = `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`.`values`
FROM `avrorades_centro`.`modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`, `avrorades_centro`.`prices_box`
WHERE `tmplvarid`= 3 
AND `contentid`= `prices_box`.`idmodx`

Родил вот такой запрос, но он ожидаемо сыплет ошибками